# How do you display images using a dataset in D3.js?

Tags: d3.js

```
var data = playoffWins([{"name": "avalanche", "wins": "2", "logo": "https://archives.bulbagarden.net/media/upload/4/4a/0025Pikachu.png" }]);
```

```
var myimage = svg.append("image")
                 .attr('xlink:href', (d) => playoffWins(d))
                 .attr('width', 50)
                 .attr('height', 50);
```

Creating a wedged pie chart, and am attempting to display images for each team's logo in a circle on the wedges but am unsure how to display the images through a data set.

Tried the code above and had no luck with the image showing up at all.
Full code here --> https://github.com/jriggs32/d3-js-projects
File name is: RadialPlayoffHockeyTeams.html

Answer (score 0):

Couple of issues here.

First, it looks like you're trying to add images without having data selected.

You first need to select the DOM elements connected to the data (check out [this](https://www.d3indepth.com/datajoins/) for a primer on data joins). For example, if I've already made the bars of my bar chart, I would select them like so:

`var bars = d3.selectAll('.bars')`

In your data set, each data point has a logo attribute. Using `.attr('xlink:href', (d) => playoffWins(d))` to access the link that contains your image doesn't make sense, because you're manually adding a data point and DOM element one at a time.

To do this correctly, once your data are already joined to your DOM elements, and the DOM elements created, you can select them as I did with `bars` above and add the logo element thus:

```
var myimage = bars.append("svg:image")
                 .attr('xlink:href', (d) => d.logo)
                 .attr('width', 50)
                 .attr('height', 50);
```